# Open file in module and keep it in memory

Tags: python

I want to implement a python module with one method, which first loads a big file and after that apply the filtering to the parameters, like this:

```
def filter(word_list):
    filtered_words = []
    special_words =  [line.strip() for line in open('special_words.txt', 'r')]
    for w in word_list:
        if not w in special_words
            filtered_words.append(w)
    return filtered_words
```

The problem is, that I want to load this file only once for the hole execution, and not every time I call this method. In Java I can just use the static blocks for this purpose, but what options do I have in python?

Comment: `'filter'` is a really bad function name. There's already a built-in with such name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to construct the word set beforehand so that you won't read the file every time you call the function. Also, you can simplify your filter function with a list comprehension:

```
with open('special_words.txt', 'r') as handle:
    special_words = {line.strip() for line in handle}

def filter(word_list):
    return [word for word in word_list if word not in special_words]
```

Comment: So the first line will be executed only once? And more thing, how can I close the file in this case?

Comment: @Le_Coeur: Yes. The `with` block creates a context manager that automatically closes the file once you leave it, so you don't need to explicitly call `handle.close()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can load the file into the list in the module's global scope; this code will only be run once, the first time the module is imported.

Answer (score 2):

To me this sounds like you want memoized functions so that when you call it with known arguments it will return the known response instead of redoing it ... this particular implementation comes from http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize

while it may be slight overkill for this problem memoize is a very useful pattern to know

```
import collections
import functools

class memoized(object):
   '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
   If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
   (not reevaluated).
   '''
   def __init__(self, func):
      self.func = func
      self.cache = {}
   def __call__(self, *args):
      if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
         # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
         # better to not cache than blow up.
         return self.func(*args)
      if args in self.cache:
         return self.cache[args]
      else:
         value = self.func(*args)
         self.cache[args] = value
         return value
   def __repr__(self):
      '''Return the function's docstring.'''
      return self.func.__doc__
   def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
      '''Support instance methods.'''
      return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)

@memoized
def get_words(fname):
   return list(open(fname, 'r')) 

@memoized
def filter(word_list):
    filtered_words = []
    special_words =  [line.strip() for line in get_words("special_words.txt")]
    for w in word_list:
        if not w in special_words
            filtered_words.append(w)
    return filtered_words
```

on a side note a neat trick is

```
 print set(word_list).difference(special_words)
```

which should be much faster (assuming you dont care about lost duplicates)

Comment: This will memoize function result for specific input params, but won't prevent file from being read again when called with different params.

Comment: You'd have to do `set(special_words) - set(word_list)`, as OP wants the words that aren't in the special words set.